# Read a file multi-threaded in python in chunks of 2KB.

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I have to read a file in chunks of 2KB and do some operation on those chunks. Now where I'm actually stuck is, when the data needs to be thread-safe. From what I've seen in online tutorials and StackOverflow answers, we define a worker thread, and override its run method. The run method uses data from a queue which we pass as an argument, and which contains the actual data. But to load that queue with data, I'll have to go through the file serially, which eliminates parallelism. I want that multiple threads read the file in parallel manner. So I'll have to cover the read part in the run function only. But I'm not sure how to go with that. Help needed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file serially is your best option since (hardware wise) it gives you the best read throughout.

*Usually* the slow part is not in the data reading but in its processing...